# Making search engine crawl my site

Tags: seo, search-engines, sitemap

I have a site with visitors from all over the world, and I'm trying to optimize indexed pages on search engines beside Google (he indexed most of my pages).

I see that on Japan search engines I'm aware of (rakuten & ocnsearch.goo) I have about 15% of my pages indexed. On Baidu & Yahoo & Bing I have only ~0.5% although I've given them sitemaps weeks ago.

How can I make other search engines crawl my site? Is there a list of sites I should submit site maps to? Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Have you submitted your website in Bing webmaster tool? if no; then do it. If yes; then see their crawling stats and review whether they are having any trouble to get your pages indexed or not.

I do not recommend any automated tools for submitting your sitemap. Start generating quality backlinks for your important pages and search engine will start indexing your pages as they find it.

Apart from this; there are many factor that affect your website indexing like:

- Quality of content (duplicate content pages are not good for indexing)
- Navigation of your website (crawler will find your pages though internal linking)
- Size of your web pages
- Website load time

Kindly try to review given point in bing webmaster tool and take necessary action if they shows any error.